# Photoshop Character style duplication using Javascript

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I need to duplicate the character style in Photoshop for one of my project through Javascript.
But even i unable to select the particular character style in Photoshop. I am new in Photoshop related scripting. Can any one look into this and help me to out from this.

Thanks

Asuvath

Comment: Please go thru [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check out [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Read [Adobe Photoshop CC Scripting Guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/scripting/photoshop-cc-scripting-guide.pdf).